How to fetch all record from parant table and only latest maching record from child table in one to many relationships spring data jpa
I have two class book and reader, using one to many relationships between book and reader. I want to retrieve all record from book and latest matching record from reader. Using spring data jpa
@Query("select b from book b left join b.reader r on r.id=(select r.id from b.reader where r.bookId=b.bookId order by r.date desc limit 1)")

I have written custom query in Jpa Repository. But it's given all records form reader table, not latest.
